# trouble with calling renderRow() on mat-table

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I would like to add rows to by Material Table when a button is clicked. But I can't seem to get the renderRows() method to call on my table.

Here is some of the relevant bit from my code:

```
<div fxFlex="20%" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center">
        <input fxFlex="10%" matInput placeholder="Part #" type="number" [(ngModel)]="partNumber">
        <input fxFlex="20%" matInput placeholder="Video Url" type="text" [(ngModel)]="videoUrl">
        <input fxFlex="40%" matInput placeholder="Download Url" type="text" [(ngModel)]="downloadUrl">
        <button mat-button [disabled]="partNumber == null || videoUrl == null" (click)="addVideo()"> <-- I would like my table to update on this click
            Add Video
        </button>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="urlCollection.length > 0">
        <mat-table #videoTable videoTable [dataSource]="dataSource">

            <-- Table columns -->

            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
```

On the TS side of things:

```
addVideo()
{
  // get data from the the inputs and add it to the table data collection;
 // Ideally I would like to have the renderRow here. 
}
```

I have tried calling renderRows() in the button click event like this:

```
<button mat-button [disabled]="partNumber == null || videoUrl == null" (click)="addVideo(); videoTable.renderRows()">
```

And like this:

```
<button mat-button [disabled]="partNumber == null || videoUrl == null" (click)="addVideo(); videoTable.table.renderRows()">
```

I get an error that goes something like "can not call renderRow() on undefined"

I have tried calling the renderRows() method in my typescript method like this:

```
@ViewChild('videoTable') videoTable: MatTableModule;
// rest of the component

addVideo()
{
    // add to the datasource collection
    this.videoTable.renderRows();
}
```

I get an "Property 'renderRows' does not exist on type 'MatTableModule'" error.

How do I update the my table when I click a button and updat my datasource ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared `videoTable` with the wrong type, it should be `MatTable`.

try with below code example:

```
import { MatTable } from '@angular/material';

@ViewChild('videoTable') videoTable: MatTable<your type>;
// rest of the component

addVideo()
{
  // add to the datasource collection
  this.videoTable.renderRows();        // call from typescript
}

// template example
// call renderRows() directly from videoTable
<button mat-button [disabled]="partNumber == null || videoUrl == null" (click)="addVideo(); videoTable.renderRows()">
```

Refer working **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dnj6gj?file=app/table-filtering-example.ts)**.